# Using "export table" on a raster attributes table in ArcGIS ModelBuilder is resulting in different results than using it outside of ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, attribute-table, export

I'm trying to build a model that after a bunch of processing exports the raster attributes table to an excel file. To do this, I figure I need to first use the "Export table" tool, followed by the "Table to Excel" tool. When I do this outside of ModelBuilder, it works perfectly, but when I add the same steps to my model, for some reason the "export table" tool only includes the first digit of a number in its output. For example, this is the original raster attributes table:

[image: raster attributes table]

and here is the same table after it has been run through the model with with "Export table" tool:

[image: attributes table after "export table" in the model]

What I have tried:

- Changing the Fields setting in the "export table" tool, including the Properties>type settings to ensure the numbers were output in long type (not that I thought this would work as the default settings of the tool are the same inside and outside of ModelBuilder)
- Using the deprecated "Table to Table" tool, but this results in the same behaviour

Does anyone know what is happening here and how I can fix it? Any work-arounds?

Comment: Copy rows tool?

Comment: @FelixIP This worked, thank you! If you post as an answer I can mark as accepted.

Comment: Self-answer is Ok, do it please. Yes, PRO is still very raw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the copy rows tool solved the problem in ModelBuilder.